# Wordpress page 2 (previous entires link) leads to blank page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I've been researching this issue for a few hours now and haven't been able to figure this out. I contacted a few support forums, but no one was willing to help.

I'm not quite sure if this is something I might have caused or if it's a wordpress issue. I know others have had the same problem.

Let me know if you have an idea of what's going on. Please keep in mind that I'm not well versed in coding.

site: http://www.brightontheday.com (previous entries link is http://www.brightontheday.com/page/2)

Comment: seems like it could be your pagination or permalink structure issue... Did you buy theme or do you know the developer? because the issue isnt that challenging

Comment: i'm using pagelines and have a package that allows support, but they told me it probably wasn't a pagelines issue. It's just me behind the site. @DavidChase

Comment: if you go to your page/2 and refresh you will see your information and the error i get is Failed to load resource which means its not loading one of your stylesheets, which is odd that pagelines wouldnt support that issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- go here:
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Choosing_your_permalink_structure
- open that settings panel in your Wordpress installation
- Set to "Default" here, this will disable the permalinks for now.
  Remember the previous setting :-)

If it works now, with the ugly URLs on, you have an issue with your permalinks.

I had this once - be sure to check for **pages** with **names** similar to **post categories**. They might have conflicting permalinks, and this is not automatically detected.

Example:
You have a Post Category "Fruit". And you also have a page called "Fruit". Then, they both (category archive and page) would be reachable by default via "www.example.com/fruit/".

This, and some certain circumstances in the template php-files (page.php with a while-loop), caused this behaviour in my case.